# Updating Sprites In Array With For Loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm messing around with JavaScript game development and I have an issue with loading sprites from an array. It works fine updating this "mob" class individually but when I use a for-loop to update them the sprite trails and repeats itself.
[image]

Here is the code associated with the sprite loader and also the code for the sprite itself.

MobLoader

```
function mobloader(){
    var self = this;
    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++){
        var t = new enemy(rInt(10, 400), rInt(10,400));
        enemies.push(t);
    }
    self.updatemobs = function(){
        for (l = 0; l < enemies.length; l++){
            enemies[l].updatemob();
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy Class (the weeds)

```
function enemy(x, y){
    var self = this;
    self.x = x;
    self.y = y;
    self.name = "Jake";
    self.enemyspr = new sprite("grasstest.png", self.x, self.y, 40, 40, 1, 1, 0, false);
    self.updatemob = function(){
        for (s = 0; s < spells.length; s++){
            if (spells[s].cy >= self.enemyspr.y && spells[s].cy <= self.enemyspr.y + self.enemyspr.h && spells[s].cx <= self.enemyspr.x + self.enemyspr.w && spells[s].cx >= self.enemyspr.x && self.enemyspr.active == true ){
                self.enemyspr.active = false;
                spells[s].spellspr.active = false;
            }
        }
        self.enemyspr.update();
    }
}
```

Basic Sprite Class

```
function sprite(src, x, y, w, h, f, l, a, loaded){
    var self = this;
    self.src = src;
    self.x = x;
    self.y = y;
    self.w = w;
    self.h = h;
    self.cf = 0;
    self.f = f;
    self.cl = 0;
    self.l = l;
    self.active = true;
    self.a = a;
    self.cfps = 0;
    self.fps = 10;
    self.loaded = loaded;
    self.spr = new Image();
    self.spr.onload = function(){self.loaded = true;}
    self.spr.src = self.src;    
    self.update = function(){
        if (self.active == true){
            self.cfps += 1;
            if (self.cfps > self.fps && self.a == 1){
                self.cfps = 0;
                self.cf += 1;
                if (self.cf >= self.f){
                    self.cf = 0;
                }
            }
            if (self.a == 3){
                if (self.f > 9){
                    self.cl = Math.floor(self.f / 10);
                    self.cf = self.f - (Math.floor(self.f / 10) * 10);
                }
                if (self.f <=9){
                    self.cf = self.f;
                    self.cl = self.l;
                }
            }
            ctx.drawImage(self.spr, self.w * self.cf, self.h * self.cl, self.w, self.h, self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h);
        }
    }
}
```

Base Class Which Clears the Canvas With Each Refresh

```
function gameupdate(){
    ctx.fillStyle = bgcolor;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    updategame();
}
setInterval(gameupdate, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the canvas before you redraw the frame.

Comment: I already do that, I think the problem comes from the for-loop updating the entities

Comment: Hello.. have you tried ctx.clearRect instead of ctx.fillRect to clear the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above. Check with a console.log to see if it is actully running, and if that doesn't work replace bgcolor with "rgb"255,255,0" just for testing, because somthing might be wrong there. Only other thing it could be is that you are spawning an entity every time he walks/frame updates. I highly, highly doubt that though.